# sqlite3 (language C): no such column

Tags: c, sqlite

I want to save the data from USB into the database sqlite3.

Here is data from USB

`char T0[8], T1[8], T2[8], T3[8], T4[8];`

I create a table with

```
const char* Temprature_table = "Create table Temprature_1 (ID INTERGER PRIMARY KEY,Thermo_0 decimal(5,1),Thermo_1 decimal(5,1),Thermo_2 decimal(5,1),Thermo_3 decimal(5,1),Thermo_4 decimal(5,1),time DATETIME)";
```

then I insert data into the table

```
result = sqlite3_exec (DB,"Insert  into Temprature VALUES(NULL, T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, time)",0,0,&errmsg);
```

or

```
char array[256];
sprintf(array, "Insert into Temprature_1 VALUES(NULL, T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, time)");
result = sqlite3_exec (DB,array,0,0,&errmsg);
```

but there is a problem: "cannot insert data: no such column: T0".
I do not know why.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please be careful how you copy material into your question; your CREATE TABLE statement tries to create a column of type INTERGER (with a stray R in the name), which won't work (or is very unlikely to work). You have a slight spelling mistake in the table name; the normal spelling is Temperature (but as you're consistent, it isn't a critical problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [prepared statements](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) to [bind values](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) to your query. A *regular* SQL has the form

```
INSERT INTO Temperature_1 (Thermo_0, Thermo_1) VALUES (23.2, 42.3)
```

A [prepared statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) looks like

```
INSERT INTO Temperature_1 (Thermo_0, Thermo_1) VALUES (?, ?)
```

which allows for security and performance enhancements. So your final code will look like

```
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

sqlite3_prepare_v2(
  db,
  "INSERT INTO Temperature (Thermo_0, Thermo_1) VALUES (?, ?)",
  -1,
  &stmt,
  NULL
);

sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, T0, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, T1, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

sqlite3_step(stmt);
```

See this [SQLite introduction](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html) to the C API. Your code doesn't work because you submit the following string to the query engine

```
INSERT INTO table (T0);
```

while the syntax of the INSERT statement [looks like](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)

```
INSERT INTO <table> VALUES (<expression>[, <expression>[, ...]])
```

When the database engine evaluates your query, it can't know that `TO` happens to be the name of a variable somewhere in your code, thus issue that error. The SQL is a language of its own, it doesn't share anything with the C context.

As a final note, the correct spelling seems to be **TEMPERATURE**, not TEMPRATURE (you missed an E after PR)

Answer (score 2):

Your C code and your SQL code is run in different domains and do not share variables. So you can not directly access C variables from SQL code. From looking at the documentation this seems to be the correct solution:

```
sqlite3_stmt *ppStmt;
sqlite3_prepare_v2(DB, "Insert into Temprature_1 VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, time)", 58, &ppStmt, NULL);

sqlite3_bind_text(ppStmt, 1, T0, 8, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(ppStmt, 2, T1, 8, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(ppStmt, 3, T2, 8, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(ppStmt, 4, T3, 8, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(ppStmt, 5, T4, 8, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

sqlite3_step(ppStmt);
sqlite3_finalize(ppStmt);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't include the *names* of C variables in the SQL query string.

You either include a verbatim value (e.g. by programmatically composing the string from smaller pieces, e.g. using `sprintf`), or you use placeholders for parameters. The latter is more robust against SQL injection attacks, and generally preferred. In the case of C as the host language, it will also save you the trouble of allocating sufficient memory for the pasted query.

You can use [placeholders](http://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam) by [creating](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) a [prepared statement](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html) and [binding parameters](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) to it. When you [execute](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html) that statement, the bound parameters will be used in the places indicated by the placeholders.